# How to remove hyphen from Google Charts I-bar?

Tags: google-visualization

Is it possible to remove these hyphens (circled red in image)? 
[image: Valid XHTML]

edit: Chart above is Line Chart with 2 series marked as interval.

Comment: Those aren't hyphens; they are an integral part of this particular style of graph (the name of the graph type escapes me at the moment).  Choose a different style of graph.

Comment: It's Line Chart with three series of data, two of them are marked as interval, it's not Candlestick Chart. And I know it's part of the default style, but I would like to change. Generally I want to create a line chart with intervals marked as simple, straight lines. I you know how to achieve that, please share your knowledge with me.

Answer (score 0):

It may be too late, but it could be useful for someone else : I used jquery for a similar need. It's not perfect but it works :

```
function changeIBar(){
    var iBar = $( '#divChart g path');
    iBar.each(function(index) {
        var d = $( this ).attr('d');
        var M = d.substring(d.indexOf('M')+1, d.indexOf(','));
        var L = d.substring(d.indexOf('L')+1, d.indexOf(',', d.indexOf(',')+1));
        if ( M != L){
            $( this ).remove()
        }
    });
}
```

Change the ID of the div element containing your chart. I don't know why but Google chart api reinitialize the i-bars after select, onmouseover and onmouseout events. So I call this function after each of these events and after ready events obviously.